# How do I add a drop shadow to image view?

Tags: android, kotlin

I couldn't find satisfying answers to this question so I'm asking here. How can I add a dropshadow to imageView to create the effect attached? I tried android:elevation="8dp" but that didn't help at all.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting your ImageView on top of CardView?

Comment: nope, can you please show me an example?

Comment: Elevation should work on API 21+, what version of Android are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:elevation="8dp"
             card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
             card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

            <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/image1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/imagep1" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```